# No value specified for parameter Java application with database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have an application with a list of people and you can change the info of one certain person when you click on a button. So I am trying to update my database but it says that I do not have a value for the 7th parameter, however I do have 7 values. When I print it, it does give me 7 values. It doesn't have a problem with the null (in my if else) because I already tried it without that.

This is my msql

```
 CREATE TABLE Persoon(
    persoonId int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    leeftijd    int(3),
    voornaam    varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    achternaam  varchar (40) NOT NULL,
    datum       date,
    locatieId   int(3),
    filmId      int(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (persoonId),
 FOREIGN KEY    (filmId) references Film(filmId),
 FOREIGN KEY    (locatieId) references Locatie(locatieId));
```

My java code

```
private void btnWijzigenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    Object geselecteerdeObject = lstPersonen.getSelectedValue();
    Persoon geselecteerdePersoon = (Persoon) geselecteerdeObject;
    if(txtLeeftijd.getText() != ""){
         try {
             String string = txtDatum.getText();
             DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
             Date datumString = format.parse(string);


             Persoon nieuwePersoon = new Persoon(geselecteerdePersoon.getPersoonId(),Integer.parseInt(txtLeeftijd.getText()), txtVoornaam.getText(), txtAchternaam.getText(),datumString,geselecteerdePersoon.getLocatieId(),geselecteerdePersoon.getFilmId());
             System.out.println("1p "+geselecteerdePersoon.getPersoonId() + " 2p " +Integer.parseInt(txtLeeftijd.getText()) + " 3p "+txtVoornaam.getText() + " 4p " + txtAchternaam.getText() + " 5p " + datumString + " 6p "+  geselecteerdePersoon.getLocatieId()+ " 7p " +geselecteerdePersoon.getFilmId());;
             PersoonDao.updatePersoon(nieuwePersoon);


         } catch (ParseException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(HoofdGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
       } 
    else{
    Persoon nieuwePersoon = new Persoon(geselecteerdePersoon.getPersoonId(),0, txtVoornaam.getText(), txtAchternaam.getText(),null,geselecteerdePersoon.getLocatieId(),geselecteerdePersoon.getFilmId());
    PersoonDao.updatePersoon(nieuwePersoon);
    }

    updatePersoonsLijst();
}
```

My method updatePersoonsLijst

```
 public void updatePersoonsLijst() {
        mijnModel.clear();
        ArrayList<Persoon> lijstVanPersonen = PersoonDao.getPersonen();

        for (Persoon huidigePersoon : lijstVanPersonen) {
            mijnModel.addElement(huidigePersoon);
        }
    }
```

And my updatePersoon

```
 public static int updatePersoon(Persoon nieuwePersoon) {
            int aantalAangepasteRijen = 0;
            try {

                aantalAangepasteRijen = Database.voerSqlUitEnHaalAantalAangepasteRijenOp("UPDATE Persoon SET leeftijd=?,voornaam=?,achternaam=?,datum=?,locatieId=?,filmId=? WHERE persoonId=?", new Object[] { nieuwePersoon.getLeeftijd(),nieuwePersoon.getVoornaam(), nieuwePersoon.getAchternaam(), nieuwePersoon.getDatum(), nieuwePersoon.getLocatieId(),nieuwePersoon.getFilmId() });
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // Foutafhandeling naar keuze
            }
            return aantalAangepasteRijen;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update statement is missing last parameter personid - your last is filmid currently.

```
aantalAangepasteRijen = Database.voerSqlUitEnHaalAantalAangepasteRijenOp("UPDATE Persoon
  SET leeftijd=?,voornaam=?,achternaam=?,datum=?,locatieId=?,filmId=? 
    WHERE persoonId=?", new Object[] 
 { nieuwePersoon.getLeeftijd(),
 nieuwePersoon.getVoornaam(), 
 nieuwePersoon.getAchternaam(), 
 nieuwePersoon.getDatum(), 
 nieuwePersoon.getLocatieId(),
 nieuwePersoon.getFilmId()

 // persoonId missing!!
  });
```

Comment: How do you mean? I do "geselecteerdePersoon.getPersoonId()" to select the personId (I am sorry the names are in Dutch).

Comment: The parameter for where persoonId =? Is not set

Comment: Or else: your update has 7 ?, you provide array with 6 values only.

Comment: oh I am sorry I see it, thank you. I am just a student and still learning how to do it.